# Raspberry Pi Wordpress install very slow

Tags: web-server

I had some problems getting this installed so I did it again on a clean wheezy latest distro. The server ran pretty fast locally with an old HTML website then when I got Wordpress installed it wouldn't work but no matter , I installed Wordpress in another /var/www/word folder.  After installing Wordpress I noticed it was my local ip in the sites URL settings. I'd known that my ip had to be used in numeric form and yes forward my http port to that specific pi but its running so slow and can't login , loses connection.  I ran top and there is very little running at all.  I notice also that it won't load on my Mac at all but will on my iPhone.   I even went in and cut the gpu mem to 16mb.   It ran well before..  I got mypi.no-ip.biz to follow my ip and for a web name , which again I doubt that service has anything running high cpu.  Would netatalk or local file server software have caused this ? Should I be using dedicated server software ? It ran fast locally...

Comment: Can you please edit this question laying out concisely what steps you've taken and what you've tried. In this format it's pretty difficult to read and understand.

Comment: Sort of incoherent, but based on the clue in the last line ("it ran fast *locally*...") I'm guessing this is a duplicate of http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9130/boost-site-speed-raspberry-pi-node-js-server -- the problem is that you are trying to run a server from inside your home with a residential ISP account.  That will be slow no matter what kind of computer you use; ISP's rate limit uploads much more than downloads and when you *download* something from a server, the server has to *upload* it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how MySQL is configured by default in your distribution, but you may try to reduce MySQL memory settings.

You can do it in `my.cnf` file, located somewhere in etc (probably `/etc/mysql`).

There should be also `mysmall.cnf` sample config file, you can replace your `my.cnf` with copy of `mysmall.cnf`.

Please make backup of `/etc/mysql` before you do something.